# Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value' to 'int'

Tags: unity, c#

I have a database which holds a list of items and properties. I am trying to fine tune this smelting station to output a certain amount of X item depending on the value found in `InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Quantity")` which should contain an `int`, but I am getting this error and even after casting it to `int` still same error.

[image]

Error:

```
Assets\Ultimate Survival\Scripts\By Namespace\UltimateSurvival\Player\Interaction\SmeltingStation.cs(161,45): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UltimateSurvival.ItemProperty.Value' to 'int'
```

Code:

```
    private void On_HolderUpdated(ItemHolder holder)
    {
        bool shouldStopBurning = false;

        if(FuelSlot.HasItem && InputSlot.HasItem)
        {
            // The items have the correct properties, and the burn process can begin.
            if(FuelSlot.CurrentItem.HasProperty("Fuel Time") && InputSlot.CurrentItem.HasProperty("Burn Time") && InputSlot.CurrentItem.HasProperty("Burn Result"))
            {
                if(IsBurning.Is(false))
                {
                    m_FuelTimeProperty = FuelSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Fuel Time");
                    m_BurnTimeProperty = InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Burn Time");
                    m_ItemResult = InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Burn Result").String;

                    IsBurning.Set(true);
                    m_BurningHandler = StartCoroutine(C_Burn());

                    return;
                }
            }
            else
                shouldStopBurning = true;
        }
        else
            shouldStopBurning = true;

        if(IsBurning.Is(true) && shouldStopBurning)
            StopBurning();
    }

    private IEnumerator C_Burn()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return m_UpdateInterval;

            // If the fuel, or the items to burn finished, stop burning.
            if(!FuelSlot.CurrentItem || !InputSlot.CurrentItem)
            {
                StopBurning();
                yield break;
            }

            var burnTime = m_BurnTimeProperty.Float;
            burnTime.Current -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
            m_BurnTimeProperty.SetValue(ItemProperty.Type.Float, burnTime);

            Progress.Set(1f - burnTime.Ratio);

            if(burnTime.Current <= 0f)
            {
                ItemData resultedItem;
                if(GameController.ItemDatabase.FindItemByName(m_ItemResult, out resultedItem))
                    CollectionUtils.AddItem(resultedItem, InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Quantity"), LootSlots);
                else
                    Debug.LogWarning("The item has burned but no result was given, make sure the item has the 'Burn Result' property, so we know what to add as a result of burning / smelting.", this);

                if(InputSlot.CurrentItem.CurrentInStack == 1)
                {
                    InputSlot.SetItem(null);
                    StopBurning();
                    yield break;
                }
                else
                {
                    burnTime.Current = burnTime.Default;
                    m_BurnTimeProperty.SetValue(ItemProperty.Type.Float, burnTime);
                    InputSlot.CurrentItem.CurrentInStack --;
                }
            }

            var fuelTime = m_FuelTimeProperty.Float;
            fuelTime.Current -= UPDATE_INTERVAL;
            m_FuelTimeProperty.SetValue(ItemProperty.Type.Float, fuelTime);

            if(fuelTime.Current <= 0f)
            {
                if(FuelSlot.CurrentItem.CurrentInStack == 1)
                {
                    FuelSlot.SetItem(null);
                    StopBurning();
                    yield break;
                }
                else
                {
                    fuelTime.Current = fuelTime.Default;
                    m_FuelTimeProperty.SetValue(ItemProperty.Type.Float, fuelTime);
                    FuelSlot.CurrentItem.CurrentInStack --;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you include as well the actual item from where you are trying to read the value?

Comment: Im not sure if thats what you were looking for but i added a picture

Comment: I meant more the code from the item itself, so anybody that tries to recreate the error does not need to guess what is behind the item itself. The screenshot only helps to fill the values, but not to recreate it. It is enough to minimize the code of the item that just handles the properties.

Comment: I figured it out, sorry for wasting time, after i looked closer at the item database i realized what i was trying to retrieve was just nested a little deeper. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Quantity")`

should be

`InputSlot.CurrentItem.GetPropertyValue("Quantity").Int.Current`